# Can I say 'a display of size around 4"'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, pronouns

Is the following sentence correct?

> I am writing to enquire whether you have available an e-paper display **of size** around 4".

What could "of size" be replaced with?

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> I am writing to enquire/inquire whether you have available **a 4" e-paper display**.

I think this is a pretty standard format, like saying:

> I think I will buy **a 50" LCD TV**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have just updated the question. I wanted to post another question but StackExchange did not let me to do it since StackExchange was seeing the new question as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: I think it is OK as I wrote it, since it is unlikely that it will be exactly 4" diagonal. It will get you close enough, then check the specs of what's available.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's correct to say "an e-paper display of size around 4" as commented by David Richerby. But, according to grammar, the more appropriate preposition  is "in". So it should be "an e-paper display in (a) size around 4".

Second, I don't think the use of the adjective "available" in the sentence is natural. I think the correct sentence should be as follows:

"......whether you have an e-paper display of size 4" available.

However, if the OP wants to get rid of the word "size", he can say "a 4" e-paper display" as replied by user 3169.

Comment: Justification? "of size" seems fine to me (native speaker).

Comment: That is a valid alternative wording but it doesn't answer the question of what could replace "of size".